# Problem when importing Maven2 project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

In my project, I have a resources directory (`src/main/resources`) that contains properties and XML files.

I want to filter only the properties files, but not any others kind of files (XML for example). Thus, I've set this in my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This is working well when I run a Maven 2 package command, i.e. both XML and properties files are included in my final JAR, and only properties files have been filtered.

However, as I want to include this project in Eclipse, when I run the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, and import the project, then I have a problem with the source declared in my project properties.

In the "Java Build Path" option of Eclipse for my project, in tab "Source", I see the `src/main/resources` directory, but Eclipse also add filters which say to exclude all java files (`Excluded: **/*.java`) and include **only** properties files (`Included: **/*.properties`).

In the `.classpath` file generated, I get this line:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" including="**/*.properties" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

This way, the JAR built by Eclipse is not correct as all my XML files are not in the JAR.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Edit, regarding this [page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html), I've added this in my `pom.xml`:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.xml</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

However, the .classpath generated is not modified with the adequate information...

---

Edit again.

The addition in my previous edit works only for version 2.6.1+ of the Eclipse plugin, not for 2.6. So, I've tried with version 2.7. However, I don't know how to force the Eclipse plugin to not define the *including* attribute:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>*</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

If I run the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command, I get the following error:

```
Request to merge when 'filtering' is not identical. Original=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[**/*.properties], exclude=[**/*.java], test=false, filtering=true, merging with=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[], exclude=[**/*.properties|**/*.java], test=false, filtering=false
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your code - do you both include and exclude `*.properties` files?

Comment: It's not a mistake. I have two subsets of resources: The first one include only the `properties` files and *filter* them. The second one exclude only the `properties` files and *does not filter* them. This is the only way I found to include all the files present in `src/main/resources` and filter only a subset of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing with the maven eclipse plugin 2.6, 2.5.1, 2.7 and 2.8-SNAPSHOT and none of them is indeed producing the expected result.

The only workaround I've been able to find is to use another directory for the resources you don't want to filter. Something like this:

```
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources1</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources2</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I agree that this is ugly. But at least, it produces a .classpath with the following entries:

```
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources1" including="**/*.properties" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources2" including="**/*.xml" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

That should allow you to deploy on Tomcat.

By the way, I wouldn't use the version 2.7 of the plugin because it's not working (see [this thread](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34952&tstart=1)). The version 2.6 may not produce the expected output but at least, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Well maven-eclipse-plugin is very bugy :( and we use version 2.5. The solution we found is copy resources to different folder. For regular maven bulid we use default filtering but for eclipse we have special **profile**. Here is maven-eclipse=plugin configuration in this profile:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-step1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/for-eclipse/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-step2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/for-eclipse/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Of course you must modify include/exclude section for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you either  the `mvn package` goal as an external tool from Eclipse. I don't think that Eclipse can handle complex Maven workflows.

Even the [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), which I use and highly recommend, has [troubles with complex workflows](http://markmail.org/message/pkuoz22ur5jub5j4#query:+page:1+mid:7h45hhbxsb3jazzn+state:results).

Answer (score 0):

Use properties to have Eclipse and Maven [build into different directories](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/project-faq.html#8). Now you can use Eclipse to quickly develop your code and use Maven to deploy it as a JAR.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse to build the JAR, use Maven. Maven will get it right.

Comment: I use Maven to build the JAR. The problem is that my library is used as a J2EE module dependency for a web application. Thus, when I publish my webapp to Tomcat inside Eclipse, the JAR created by Eclipse does not include my XML files...

Comment: Use maven to deploy to Tomcat. Change your code so you can test everything inside of Eclipse without deploying. MockRunner is your friend.